# PHP ActiveRecord - How to list out the all table names of a MySql database?

Tags: php, mysql, phpactiverecord

I m using [PHP ActiveRecord](http://www.phpactiverecord.org/) in my application

How to list all the table names of the database

Here i had configured the connection of database as below

```
require_once ActiveRecordDIR.'/ActiveRecord.php';
ActiveRecord\Config::initialize(function($cfg){


    $cfg->set_model_directory('core/models');
    $cfg->set_connections(array('development' =>'mysql://root:pass@localhost/dbname'));
});
```

After this i wanna list out all the table names in database "dbname"

Comment: Where is the question? What have you tried and where is the problem with that?

Comment: I think the problem is executing custom queries with PAR ORM.

Comment: In custom query we can access only the specified table; but i want all the table names of database

Comment: [AR Documentation](http://www.phpactiverecord.org/docs/ActiveRecord/Connection#methodtables)

Comment: George dont know how to use that method thats the problem. can u help me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An [Active Record](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/activeRecord.html) represents a single row in single table and adds business logic to it, so pattern-wise there should be no way to query all the tables in the database from an ActiveRecord because there is no use-case for that in the pattern.

However, according to that framework's docs you can use

- [`Connection::query()`](http://www.phpactiverecord.org/docs/ActiveRecord/Connection#methodquery) - Execute a raw SQL query on the database.

and thus use raw SQL to fetch all the table names. I take you know the SQL for that.

There also is a method

- [`Connection::query_for_tables()`](http://www.phpactiverecord.org/docs/ActiveRecord/Connection#methodquery_for_tables) -  Query for all tables in the current database. The result must only contain one column which has the name of the table.

which might be doing what you are trying to do.

Comment: This is very correct.  I like how you looked at the docs and figured out a very direct way to do this. @Kaviarasan  `ActiveRecord\Connection::instance()->query_for_tables()`.

Comment: $tab = ActiveRecord\Connection::instance()->query('show tables');
         $tabs = $tab->fetchAll();
         print_r($tabs);

Answer (score 3):

The method **[`Connection::tables()`](http://www.phpactiverecord.org/docs/ActiveRecord/Connection#methodtables)** returns an array of all tables in your database. You can then foreach the array to retrieve the table names.

Comment: George dont know how to use that method thats the problem. can u help me with some script?

Comment: Well, if for example you have Connection $test = new Connection(); then you do $tables = $test->tables(); and the table names are stored in an array... if you need to retrieve from the array you can do a [foreach](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php) on that array.

Comment: the problem with this is that Class Connection is an abstract class so we cant instantiate it

Comment: You're not supposed to instantiate it, you're supposed to use call it via your class which extends ActiveRecord\Model. I showed it as an instantiation to explain how it would normally work. You can call it as `Test::tables();`

Comment: i try to use => ActiveRecord\Connection::query("SHOW TABLES"); but its showing the error => Strict Standards: Non-static method ActiveRecord\Connection::query() should not be called statically

Comment: ActiveRecord\Connection::tables() doesn't take any arguments and returns an array with all table names... You don't have to use query()

Comment: Sir, im getting this error ->  Strict Standards: Non-static method ActiveRecord\Connection::tables() should not be called statically in D:\xampp\htdocs\apps\db.php on line 30

Fatal error: Using $this when not in object context in D:\xampp\htdocs\apps\ActiveRecord\lib\Connection.php on line 353

Comment: Is your class extending ActiveRecord\Model?

Comment: No, its not extending from any class

Comment: Well, try to extend it (if you're using a framework, your class should be a model by the way) and see what happens... I believe it should.

Answer (score 1):

```
YourModel::find_by_sql("SELECT `TABLE_NAME` FROM `information_schema`.`TABLES` WHERE `TABLE_SCHEMA`=?",array('YOUR_DB_NAME'));
```

Comment: Thx lot. Its providing the table name; But after setting the connection to database, i want to display the table names; without using any model; any idea plz